# Change Data Capture PostgreSQL to Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

In my project I have PostgreSQL database as main DB and I need to keep synchronized my neo4j DB. To do so I want to use Debezium for CDC, kafka and neo4j streams plugin. One of the reasons I prefer Debezium to jdbc is because [it's real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60908891/kafka-connect-jdbc-vs-debezium-cdc/60908892#60908892). So at this point I want to get

```
PostgreSQL -> Debezium -> Kafka -> Confluent -> Neo4j
```

[from documentation I found](https://neo4j.com/labs/kafka/4.1/kafka-connect/?_gl=1*1optitr*_ga*NTk3NjU4MTU2LjE2MTgzODE0NjY.*_ga_DL38Q8KGQC*MTYzOTg5NjA5NS4zMjcuMS4xNjM5OTAyODk2LjA.&_ga=2.268540593.1997448648.1639622948-597658156.1618381466&_gac=1.15693508.1638371211.Cj0KCQiA15yNBhDTARIsAGnwe0XDRvVBG7jnaUaL7wctSZnhySl3Xhe2sd2gzjUBCFk8JrLTqrT_tDcaAgrYEALw_wcB#kafka-connect-sink-strategies) sink Neo4j CDC but only from another Neo4j DB.

```
Sink ingestion strategies
Change Data Capture Event
This method allows to ingest CDC events coming from another Neo4j Instance.
```

Why only from another Neo4j instance? I am confused because I don't understand how exactly I should implement Change data Capture from PostgreSQL to neo4j.

Comment: You can import data from Kafka Sink to Neo4j from various sources, what you are looking at is syncing two Neo4js with Kafka CFC

Comment: @TomažBratanič I couldn't find anything on topic Kafka CFC, is it change file capture ? Could you share some links for docs, articles ?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? The recommended by Tom isn’t useful…  is it?

Comment: @sAguinaga Nope